# how to query mongodb from nodejs via mongojs module ? (server is openshift)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, openshift, mongojs

I was trying out mongodb and nodejs on openshift, using mongojs to interface between nodejs and mongodb.

In mongoshell I ran "use nodejs" and defined a "scores" collection. I saved some data in it and its correctly showing.

In app.js file of nodeserver
I have

```
self.routes['/db'] = function(req, res) {
var db = require("./db");
        db.scores.find(function(err,docs){res.send(docs);});        
    };
```

and in db.js file I have

```
var dbName = "/nodejs";
var databaseUrl = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_USERNAME + ":" +  process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD + "@" + process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST + ":" +  process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT+ dbName;
// "username:password@example.com/mydb"
var collections = ["scores"]
var db = require("mongojs").connect(databaseUrl, collections);
module.exports = db;
```

I am unable to get any data when I go to url  mydomain.com/db

Can someone please point out what  am doing wrong. The database is connecting. I am unable to find all from scores collection.

```
self.routes['/db'] = function(req, res) {
    var db = require("./db");
    db.scores.find(function(err,docs){res.send(docs);});        
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While your question seems well thought-out, I'd advise changing the title of your question to better describe the problem you're facing, such as "Node.js with MongoDB and Openshift not routing correctly".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think that would be more helpful for someone in the future. Will change it accordingly. Also its not about routing. Just unable to query correctly from nodejs to mongodb via mongojs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The db connection configuration I saved in a separate file was the one causing error. This configuration worked and I was able to fetch db entries. Use either the commented out block OR the code below that. Both does the same thing. Just posting this answer for anyone trying out on openshift.

```
self.routes['/db'] = function(req, res) {
        var dbName = "/nodejs";
        var connection_string = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_USERNAME + ":" +  process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD + "@" + process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST + ":" +  process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT + dbName;
        var db = mongojs(connection_string);

        /*
        var b = db.collection('books');    
        db.b.find(function(err, docs) {
           res.send(docs); 
        });*/
        db.collection('books').find(function(err,docs){
            res.send(docs);
        });
    };
```

nodejs is the database name used in which the collection "books" were stored.
Defined var mongojs=require('mongojs'); at the very top where all variables were declared, though it doesn't matter if its just declared before mongojs variable is used.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should use the collection method to use your score collection. Like the following:

```
db.collection('scores').find(function(err,docs){res.send(docs);});
```

Or use the toArray function to be sure to retrieve an array of objects.

```
db.collection('scores').find().toArray(function(err, docs) {
    console.dir(docs);
    res.send(docs)
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for your response. The way I tried to save my db connection configuration in a seperate file was wrong.

Comment: self.routes['/db'] = function(req, res) {
     var dbName = "/nodejs";
     var connection_string = process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_USERNAME + ":" +  process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD + "@" + process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST + ":" +  process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT + dbName;
     var db = mongojs(connection_string);
     var b = db.collection('books');

     //db.b.find(function(err, docs) {
       // res.send(docs); 
     //});
db.collection('books').find(function(err,docs){
 res.send(docs);
  });
 };

Answer (score 1):

> this is how we connect to our MongoDB server:

```
//app.js
var databaseUrl = "mydb"; // "username:password@example.com/mydb"
var collections = ["users"]
var db = require("mongojs").connect(databaseUrl, collections);



 db.users.find({email: "abcd@gmail.com"}, function(err, users) {
  if( err || !users) console.log("No female users found");
  else users.forEach( function(femaleUser) {
    console.log(femaleUser);
  } );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using MongoClient.

```
//test is the database and students is the collection inside test.
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', function(err, db) {
    console.log("Successfully connected to MongoDB ");
    var cursor = db.collection('students').find({});

    cursor.forEach(
        function(doc) {
           console.log("JSON doc: "+doc);
        },
        function(err) {
            console.log("Error");
            return db.close();
        }
    );

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code in Node to connect to a MongoDB collection and return the results as an array.

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const credentials = require("../credentials.js");

const dbUrl = 'mongodb://' + credentials.username +
    ':' + credentials.password + '@' + credentials.host + ':' + credentials.port + '/' + credentials.database;

MongoClient.connect(dbUrl, (err, client) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Successfully connected');

    let collection = client.db(credentials.database).collection('products');

    collection.find({}).toArray((err, docs) => {
        console.log(docs);
        client.close();
    });
});
```

here's the credentials.js file for the MongoDB connection

```
module.exports = {
    host:     'localhost',
    port:       '27017',
    username: 'user',
    password: 'secret',
    database: 'your_db'
}
```